How to get the list of application-defined hooks currently installed by running processes in windows?
I would like to know how, if possible, I could enumerate running processes and access hooks installed by each process if any. I found this blog from 2006 but I am having difficulty replicating it. I assume this might be due to changes in windows internal structures.
Is there a way to achieve this or are there recent references to similar adventure?
